# why webgl canvas context use much more memory than 2d canvas?

Tags: canvas, webgl

1024x1024 2d canvas may use about 1024 * 1024 * 4 = 4M memory,but webGL context use at least 5-10 times more memory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    
        <div style="display:inline-block ;overflow: hidden;width: 512px;height: 512px;">
            <canvas id="canvas" width="1024" height="1024" style="border: red 1px solid;transform: scale(0.5); transform-origin: 0 0;">old version need update</canvas>
        </div>
    </body>

    <script>
        var ctx = window.document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("webgl")
        var gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");

    </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are possibly multiple reasons

#### By default a webgl canvas is anti-aliased.

The browser chooses the amount but checking

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const samples = gl.getParameter(gl.SAMPLES) || 1;
console.log(`samples is ${samples} so this canvas is actually ${gl.canvas.width * samples} x ${gl.canvas.height * samples} pixels big internally`);
```

On my machine a 300x150 canvas is actually 1200x600 because that's [how a GPU's built in antialiasing works](https://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/msaa-overview/)

You can turn off anti-aliasing by passing in `antialias: false` when creating the context

```js
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('webgl', {
  antialias: false,
});
const samples = gl.getParameter(gl.SAMPLES) || 1;
console.log(`samples is ${samples} so this canvas is actually ${gl.canvas.width * samples} x ${gl.canvas.height * samples} pixels big internally`);
```

#### WebGL is double buffered

So there will always be at least 2 buffers allocated, the drawing buffer (the buffer you render to) and a copy used for rendering the page. So even with antialiasing off there will be 2 buffers where as 2D canvas might have only 1 (it's up to the browser what it does for canvas 2D)

#### WebGL requires a GL context and related support

WebGL internally in the browser creates some kind of context to track all the state. That state is per WebGL context. In other words if you create 2 WebGL contexts the browser needs to track 2 sets of WebGL state. In Chrome that includes things like the command buffer and other buffers to transfer commands and data from the process running the webpage to the process talking to the GPU. That by itself can be 2-4 meg. Canvas 2D on the other hand most likely allocates that info once and shares it across all canvases. It might not even be accounted for when looking at memory usage.

Comment: thanks very much , i don't realize that webgl use ssaa to anti-aliased. and on my machine the params is 8.

Comment: Can developer control the built-in webgl anti-aliasing params? Turn off the ssaa samples 8 is terrible,can i set small samples param,or i have to do the antialias myself using msaa or other antialias tech.

Comment: You can't set the canvas's anti-aliasing except to false (off) or true (let the browser decide). You can render to a texture via a framebuffer and do whatever processing you want to it when rendering that to the canvas. You can also make the canvas larger than it's displayed and get bilinear filtering when it's composited. In WebGL2 you can create your own multi-sample renderbuffers but not in WebGL1